# Resizing issues with xib while adding constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xib, xcode-storyboard

I am new to this and kind of stuck in understanding how to resolve it.

I have a view (freeform) created in xib and I want to add constraints to the view based on the sizes.

[image]

Each of the button is inside a view. I want to add the constraints for all of them such that based on the screen size they automatically resize. When I try to "Add missing Constraints" it just messes up the whole view. Can anyone help me understand how the resizing works when we would have to divide the screen such that 3 views are equally divided. ( 3 on the top half and 3 on the bottom half)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @Rob Can I not add constraints to this implementation ?

Comment: Yes definitely, you can give fixed size to left and right and give them leading and trailing respectively and the centre one will have to get leading from left and trailing from right. But, that's not ideal as every screen have different size and the output may not be identical. Best will be to use `UICollectionView` or `StackView`

Comment: @Rob Since these are buttons in the views, we would want them to resize accordingly. Fixing the size of the left and right would only resize the middle one as bigger. Can't we resize all of them using something like `horizontally in the container` so that the screen is divided into 3 parts and all 3 views have equal width and equal height ?

Comment: Yes, use `UIStackView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach allows you to create a *dynamically* resizable xib with a *set* amount of subviews/buttons.

Since you mention "Add missing constraints" I will assume you're using AuotLayout. First of all, I recommend you to not use "Add missing constraints" as it's very unpredictable, and you'll rarely receive the result you want.

**To add a Static amount of buttons to a xib I would do the following:**

1. Select all the Buttons in each row
2. Choose the "Embed In" option (in the lower right corner) and pick "Stack View", your views will resize but they're now added to a dynamically resizing UIStackView.
   [image]
3. Now do the same with the second row of buttons.
4. Select each Stack View and make sure they have their Distribution option set to "Fill Equally" to give each button the same size.
   [image]
5. Now select both Stack Views, and yet again add them both to a Stack View. This Stack View also needs its Distribution set to "Fill Equally".
   [image]
6. You may now add your own constraints. Select the "Add New Constraints" option to manually add them. They may be whatever you desire, I set mine to 20px from each side.
   [image]
7. You should now have a dynamically resizing Button XIB with a Static amount of Buttons!

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. I followed the same steps as yours. but I am getting all the buttons overlapping each other in top left corner of the screen.

Comment: @dper That's strange. Please check the alignment, distribution, and spacing of your 3 stack views. To replicate your desired screenshot I'd set it to something like: `Alignment: Fill`, `Distribution: Fill Equally`, and `Spacing: 10`. This goes for all your StackViews.  
Also, make sure you only manually add the constraints _on_ the parent StackView (the one we add both the other stack views to), to something like 20 to each side. You would rarely add constraints _inside_ of a StackView, as the StackView handles the content sizing by the above-mentioned attributes.

Comment: Hey @Kim, I finally found out the issue. It wasn't with the stack view. It was because the layout of the view was not taking the frame that I was providing. fixed it by overiding layoutSubviews and adding frame there. It was a great learning. Thank you for the help.